# Razor Not Compiling User Defined Variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm making a website that displays some information from a custom-made Event class, which has some data in it, including a timestamp, a string, a list, etc.

In my view, I have a model which contains an object which contains a list of Events.  I iterate through the list and for each event, display the data it contains.  This means that I have a lot of `@Model.IntermediateClass.EventList[eventListIndex].propertyToDisplay` in my code, which is not very readable, but works perfectly fine.

To improve readability, inside my for loop, I'm creating a variable currentEvent and having it contain @Model.IntermediateClass.EventList[eventListIndex] so that I can simply have `currentEvent.propertyToDisplay`, a lot nicer looking.  I defined it inside the loop so that I would have access to the index of the event.

However, when I do this, I get the most generic Razor error possible: "Razor Compilation Error. We tried, we really did, but we just can't compile your view."  I think this is because the variable type is of my custom Event class, because I also have an integer variable holding the number of events in the list, and that variable compiles and works just fine. I know that the type of my variable is correct because if I do not define it correctly, I get a more specific error complaining about the type.

Furthermore, including any using statements at the top of the file like this `@{using statements}` causes a compiler error as well.  In my variable declaration, which would require a using statement, I am instead inline specifying what I am using, also annoyingly verbose.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?  While refactoring my code like this is not technically necessary to it working correctly, I am very frustrated that such a simple way to clean it up does not work.

If anyone could help provide a little clarity, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my relevant razor code:

```
@{
    Layout = "Layout/MasterTabs.cshtml";
}

@section EventTableContent {

    <!--Table of event summary info-->
    <table>

        <tr>
            <th class="col_index" rowspan="2">Event #</th>
            <th class="col_timestamp" rowspan="2">Timestamp</th>
            <th class="col_data" colspan="2">Event Data</th>
            <th class="break_lines" rowspan="2">Raw Log Line</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="col_data">Label</th>
            <th class="col_data">Description</th>
        </tr>

        @for (var eventListIndex = 0; eventListIndex < @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList.Count; eventListIndex++)
        {
            //Symbotic.LifeOfOrder.Models.Event.Event currentEvent = @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex];
            int numberOfDataItems = @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList.Count;

            <tr>
                @if (numberOfDataItems == 1)
                {
                    <td class="col_index centered"><a name="@eventListIndex.ToString()">Event @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Index</a></td>
                        <td class="column_timestamp centered">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Timestamp</td>
                        <td class="column_label">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[0].Label</td>
                        <td class="column_description">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[0].Description</td>
                        <td>@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].RawLogLine</td>
                }
                else if (numberOfDataItems > 1)
                {
                    <td class="col_index centered" rowspan="@numberOfDataItems.ToString()">Event @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Index</td>
                        <td class="column_timestamp centered" rowspan="@numberOfDataItems.ToString()">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Timestamp</td>
                        <td class="column_label">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[0].Label</td>
                        <td class="column_description">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[0].Description</td>
                        <td rowspan="@numberOfDataItems.ToString()">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].RawLogLine</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td class="col_index centered">Event @Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Index</td>
                        <td class="column_timestamp centered">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].Timestamp</td>
                        <td class="column_label"></td>
                        <td class="column_description"></td>
                        <td>@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].RawLogLine</td>
                }
            </tr>

            for (var dataListItems = 1; dataListItems < numberOfDataItems; dataListItems++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="column_label">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[dataListItems].Label</td>
                    <td class="column_description">@Model.Analysis.OrderInformation.EventList[eventListIndex].DataList[dataListItems].Description</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>

}
```

The whole section thing fits into a master layout I have made separately

Comment: Can you add the pertinent view code?

Comment: In a Razor view, it's just `@using namespace` without `{ }` or `;`

Comment: Need to see the Razor code please.

Comment: Where is model defined for this?

Comment: The model is defined in a nancy module.  I know that everything is connected properly because the information currently displays perfectly fine.  It's the refactoring I'm having trouble with.